# Распарсить Json файл с несколькими массивами

Tags: android

Есть json файл такой структуры:

```
{
  "kitchen": {
    "traditional": [
      {
        "title": "Блюдо 1",
        "ingredients": "Что-то",
        "description": "Что-то",
        "image": "none",
        "favorites": "0",
        "category": "Традиционные блюда"
      },
      {
        "title": "Блюдо 2",
        "ingredients": "Что-то",
        "description": "Что-то",
        "image": "none",
        "favorites": "0",
        "category": "Традиционные блюда"
      }
    ],
    "sladkoe": [
      {
        "title": "Пирог 1",
        "ingredients": "Что-то",
        "description": "Что-то",
        "image": "none",
        "favorites": "0",
        "category": "Сладкое"
      },
      {
        "title": "Пирог 2",
        "ingredients": "Что-то",
        "description": "Что-то",
        "image": "none",
        "favorites": "0",
        "category": "Сладкое"
      }
    ],
    "napitki": [
      {
        "title": "Напиток 1",
        "ingredients": "Что-то",
        "description": "Что-то",
        "image": "none",
        "favorites": "0",
        "category": "Напитки"
      },
      {
        "title": "Напиток 2",
        "ingredients": "Что-то",
        "description": "Что-то",
        "image": "none",
        "favorites": "0",
        "category": "Напитки"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Как распарсить его? Пытался сделать так, но не получается.

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String resultJson = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("kitchen.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        resultJson = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return resultJson;
}

//Класс парсит JSON и извлекает данные из него
private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String resultJson = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return loadJSONFromAsset();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);

        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;

        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            JSONArray traditionalArray = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("traditional");

            for (int i = 0; i < traditionalArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject titleObject = traditionalArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String title = titleObject.optString("title");
                traditionalDishesArray.add(title);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

В итоге, мне нужно каждую группы Традиционные блюда, Сладкое, Напитки из них вытащить title.

Answer (score 1):

Для сериализации и десериализации java объектов в JSON используйте библиотеку [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) от Google.

Тогда работа с ArrayList<> получается что то вроде `List<GoodsItem> listItemsDes = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr,itemsListType);`

Статьи, которые помогут подробнее разобраться:

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library/gson.php

http://www.javenue.info/post/gson-json-api

https://habrahabr.ru/post/253266/

Comment: мм мне хотелось бы на моем примере чтобы нашли ошибку мою. т.к. для другого примера все работает когда в json файле 1 массив допустим с объектами, а когда усложнил структуру, то перестало работать

Comment: У вас проблема в том, что вы игнорируете первый массив "kitchen" и сразу переходите к массиву "traditional".

Comment: а как получить доступ к внутреннему массиву?

Comment: У вас должен получиться массив с массивами. Перебираем первый массив (в нём один элемент) "кухня", из него извлекаем уже три массива.

Comment: Мне казалось что можно по названию массива обратиться и извлекать данные, если даже массив вложенный. На другом примере делал, но я удалил к сожалению тот проект :(

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем вытаскивать массив, нужно вытащить объект JSON с ключом "kitchen". Попробуйте так:

```
...
dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
JSONObject innerJSONObject = dataJsonObj.getJSONObject("kitchen");
JSONArray traditionalArray = innerJSONObject.getJSONArray("traditional");
...
```